# Rails3 jquery mobile All Conditional Items showing up in the Nav Bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

The following nav bar code produces a nav bar with 6 slots when logged out (e.g. Send, Get, Account, Sign in, Full, and blank.  The max for the nav bar is 5 items without wrapping.  I want jquery mobile to recognize that there are only 5 items.  Is there some syntax for accomplishing this?

![navbar]: http://ponzicode.com/so/navbar.jpg

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Send",  %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Get",   %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Account", root_path %></li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if mobile_device? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Full", :mobile => 0 %></li>
        <% else %>
           <li><%= link_to "Mobile", :mobile => 1 %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :prepare_for_mobile

   private

   def mobile_device?
     if session[:mobile_param]
      session[:mobile_param] == "1"
     else
       request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
     end
   end

   helper_method :mobile_device?

   def prepare_for_mobile
     session[:mobile_param] = params[:mobile] if params[:mobile]
     request.format = :mobile if mobile_device?
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this copied from your project?  Your code should only be producing 5 `<li>` elements by my count.

I notice the second `<ul>` element is not a close tag--that should be `</ul>`

**Edit:**

Try commenting out your code and pasting this in:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to "Test", "" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Test", "" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Test", "" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Test", "" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Test", "" %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Something tells me that this is going to wrap too--in which case 4 is your max (at least with the current styling)

Comment: I agree with you on the 5 <li>s but the result is 5 with a blank item position.  I'm going to try and put up a screen shot. As for the <ul>, I edited the closing tag to reflect what it is in my code </ul>.  I copied and pasted it from my code, the only thing I can think of is pressed Ctrl-K to format the code it changed that tag.

Comment: could you also paste in the snippet this renders to on mobile and on desktop?

Comment: Ah, I meant the HTML code generated.  The image actually looks like there are only 5 `li`s.  Have you been able to make an unordered list with 5 list items that does **not** wrap?  It's possible that this is a sizing issue (test it out by using the code in my edit)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I tested it and the same thing happens, even when the link test is 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: Received an answer in jquery mobile forum, you must use either add data-grid="d" to the data-role or .ui-grid-d to the list. A reference in the docs can be found here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b3/docs/content/content-grids.html.